# Como insertar el valor de un checkbox dentro de mi tabla mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla de solicitudes  y lo que quiero hacer es un UPDATE que cuando marque el checkbox de varias de ellas se me actualice  la base de datos que todas las seleccionadas están en ruta. pero no entiendo como captar los valores multiples de los  checkbox y guardarlos en la columna ruta. Gracias

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM contribuyente  order by id LIMIT 
 $offset,$per_page");

if ($numrows>0){
  ?>
  <div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <form action="checkruta.php" method="post" >
<table class="my-table">

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
     <th>Folio</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
     <th>Fecha Solicitud</th>
      <th>Solicitud</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Fecha reporte</th>
      <th>Seleccionar Ruta</th>
      <th><input type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar"/></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[6];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[7];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[8];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[10];?></td>
      <?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cbox1' value='en ruta'> <br></td>";
      ?>

    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniela, no veo en tu codigo donde declaras las variables `$numrows` ni `$res`

Answer (score 0):

En el ultimo valor de cada fila podrias poner algo como :

`<?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cbox1' name='rutas[]' value='<?php echo $row[0];?>'> <br></td>";?>`

Y en tu script que recibe la informacion tendrias algo como :

```
if( !empty( $_POST[ 'rutas' ] ) ) {

foreach( $_POST[ 'rutas' ] as $ruta ) {
    // Aqui se imprimiria el id de la tabla que necesitas actualizar,
   // solo si ese checkbox fue seleccionado       
    echo $ruta; 
}
```

Comment: Hola una duda porque me sale este error si defini mi variable , if( !empty( $_POST[ 'rutas' ] ) ) {

foreach( $_POST[ 'rutas' ] as $ruta ) {

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdpagina");
 $query="UPDATE contribuyente SET ruta = '$ruta' WHERE contribuyente. id = '$id'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 echo "Data Inserted Successfully!";
        
    echo $ruta;           Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login18\Login\vista\checkruta.php on line 15
Data Inserted Successfully!